# wordpress PHP theme function switch brought whole site down

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

2 lines of code switched broght my whole site down. All i wanted to do was switch the excerpt length for the blog. So i switched out two lines of code inbetwen a function but then lost those lines of code on accident! This is a total disaster. I can login to wp-admin and some of the links on the site do not work.

here are the lines of code i switched:

```
function avada_excerpt_length( $length ) {

(this used to be two lines of short code, i remember the code $length was   somewhere in it)

}
```

This is what I replaced it with

```
function avada_excerpt_length( $length ) {

return: 55;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a syntax error:

```
return: 55;
```

should be:

```
return 55;
```

Comment: still down... i even deleted it before i did it and the site jus twill not allow me to login to wp-admin

Comment: Avada is a third party theme. If you switch to the default theme, you should be able to bypass any problems that Avada is causing. You can change the theme by updating the database directly: http://designgala.com/how-to-change-wordpress-theme-directly-from-database/

Comment: If that doesn't help, we'll need some more debug information. Does the browser print any kind of error? If not, check your error log for additional details.

Answer (score 2):

The two missing lines ( if you are specifically searching for two ) were probably :

```
$length = 55;
return $length;
```

Which is exactly the same like @Chris Hanson wrote in his answer .

You also need to activate the filter , which can also be your *"second missing line"*
this is a standard function from the [CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Control_Excerpt_Length_using_Filters) ;

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

or in your case :

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'avada_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

ALl the theme author did was changing a bit the function´s name and adding their own prefix.

You probably commented out the function lines, ( or in your terms *"switched"* ), but left the filter still activated .
If you want to turn it off, you should disable ( comment ) the `FILTER`  and not the `FUNCTION`.

At any rate , you should still be able to log in to the admin side and switch to any other theme ..